# Unable to write xpath for a dynamic web element

Tags: selenium, xpath, dynamic

In a user profile page there is a dynamic expand icon to view more information.
After clicking this icon , 3 matching expand icons are found on the page. What is the `xpath` for the first expand icon?

After inspecting the icon I am getting the `xpath` as

```
.//*[@id='jobsContent']/ul/li/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a
```

but there are 3 matching nodes.

Here is the html code for the first icon which i want to click :

```
<a class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: $parent.toggle, attr: { 'title': linkLabel }, css: { fa: true, 'fa-search-minus': expanded(), 'fa-search-plus': !expanded() }" title="Expand"/>
```

Comment: Could you decrease `HTML` code sample to leave just a part for target elements. Also add more details about your problem as it not quite clear

Comment: The last line of the code <a class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: $parent.toggle, attr: { 'title': linkLabel }, css: { fa: true, 'fa-search-minus': expanded(), 'fa-search-plus': !expanded() }" title="Expand"/> is the code for the target element

Answer (score 0):

To match target element only, you can try to select it by its index with this `XPath`:

```
//a[@title="Expand"][position()=n]
```

if all of those elements are children of the same parent

Change `n` with exact index of target element.

Note that in `Xpath` index count starts from `1`, but not from `0`..

If they have different parents you might use

```
findElements(By.xpath('//a[@title="Expand"]')).get(n) # Java
find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@title="Expand"]')[n] # Python
```

Note that in most of programming languages index count starts from `0`

Comment: Tried that..the problem is that there are 2 more nodes with this same html code..so 3 matching nodes are found!

Comment: i tried //a[@title="Expand"][position()=1 ] but all 3 matching nodes in the page are found.

Comment: and what about complex programming solution? did you try to find element by index in list of elements?

Comment: yes i could get the xpath for the first expand button but it was tedious:.//*[@id='profilePageTabContent']/div/div[1]/ul/li/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a

Comment: you can simplify it as `//li[a[@title="Expand"]][1]`

Comment: Tried //li[a[@title="Expand"]][1] but 3 matching nodes are found in the page

Comment: `//li[a[@title="Expand"]][position()=1 ]` same result?

Comment: ok. Could you share the link to the page or show piece of `HTML` code that covers all 3 links?